# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity, 2 controllers redirect each to different login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have 2 controllers

- TestController
- DemoController

Both they use `[Authorize]` attribute and default identity to login: email+password.

My question: How can I redirect all unauthenticated requests going TestControoler, to TestAccountController/Login and all requests going to DemoController to DemoAccountController/Login ?

the reason for that is that I want to have 2 login environments for 2 different purposes.

Answer (score 4):

ASP.net core supports multiple authentication schemes.

You could add two by adding the following to your Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddCookie("scheme1", options => { options.LoginPath = "/login1"; })
  .AddCookie("scheme2", options => { options.LoginPath = "/login2"; });
```

And then specify the scheme to use in the controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "scheme1")]
public sealed class SampleController : Controller
{
  //...
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x for additional details